# OLá, sou iniciante em python, estou com problemas pra conseguir calcular o valor final usando as variaveis dentro das funções, como resolver?

Tags: python, funções

```
print('Bem-vindo(a) à copiadora da Cecília Siqueira Müller')
print()

servico = 0
paginas = 0
extra = 0
valorserv = servico * paginas + extra

def escolha_servico():
  while True:
    print('Entre com o serviço desejado:')
    print('DIG - Digitalização')
    print('ICO - Impressão Colorida')
    print('IBO - Impressão Preto e Branco')
    print('FOT - Fotocópia')
    servico = input('>>> ').upper()
    if servico == 'FOT' or servico == 'IBO' or servico == 'ICO' or servico == 'DIG':
      if servico == 'FOT':
        return 0.2
        break
      elif servico == 'IBO':
        return 0.4
        break
      elif servico == 'ICO':
        return 1
        break
      else:
        return 1.1
        break
    else:
     print('Serviço Inválido. Tente novamente:')
     continue

def num_pagina():
  while True:
    valorserv = 0
    paginas = int(input('Entre com o número de páginas: '))
    if paginas < 20:
      return paginas
      break
    elif paginas >= 20 and paginas < 200:
      return paginas * (15/100)
      break
    elif paginas >= 200 and paginas < 2000:
      return paginas * (20/100)
      break
    elif paginas >= 2000 and paginas < 20000:
      return paginas * (25/100)
      break
    else:
      print('Não aceitamos pedidos acima da quantidade de 20000 páginas.')
      print('Por favor, entre com o número de páginas novamente!')
      continue

def servico_extra():
  print('Deseja adicionar mais algum serviço?')
  print('1 - Encadernação simples - R$10,00')
  print('2 - Encadernação Capa Dura  - R$25,00')
  print('0 - Não desejo serviço extra')
  extra = int(input('>>> '))
  while True:
    if extra == 1 or extra == 2 or extra == 0:
      if extra == 1:
       return 10
      elif extra == 2:
       return 25
      else:
       return 0
    else:
     print('Serviço extra inválido. Tente novamente:')
     continue


escolha_servico()
num_pagina()
servico_extra()


valorserv = servico * paginas + extra


print('total: {} * {} + {} = {}.'.format(servico, paginas, extra, valorserv))
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.